# How to compute the sensitivity of this control system?

Tags: control, control-system, sensitivity

I am learning control systems on my own and am having some trouble understanding how Richard C. Dorf and Robert H. Bishop found \$S^{T}_{G}\$ in *Modern Control Systems* (12th edition):

---

**The problem:**

[image]

[image]

---

**The corresponding answer:**

[image]

---

Where does, the very first equation, $$\frac{1}{1+GH(s)}$$ come from? No matter what I try I never find this equation. Could someone please explain and show how he got this equation? It doesn't seem to be the equation of the entire system because - according to what I tried - this equation should be $$T=\frac{RG_CG}{1+HG_CG}$$

I know how he found \$S^G_\tau\$:

$$S^G_\tau = \frac{\tau}{G} \frac{\partial G}{\partial \tau}$$

$$\frac{\tau}{\frac{100}{\tau s+1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial{\tau}}(\frac{100}{\tau s+1})$$

$$S^G_\tau = \frac{-\tau s}{s\tau +1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the two expressions:

$$T=\frac{G_c G }{1+ H G_c G}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S_G^T=\frac{\partial T}{\partial G}\frac{G}{T} $$

Compute the first term:

$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial G} = \frac{G_c }{1+H G_c G}- \frac{H G_c^2 G }{(1+HG_c G)^2}= \frac{G_c+H G_c^2 G-H G_c^2 G }{(1+H G_c G)^2}=\frac{G_c }{(1+H G_c G)^2}$$

And substitute values to get the final expression:

$$ S_G^T= \frac{G_c }{(1+H G_c G)^2}\frac{G}{\frac{G_c G }{1+ H G_c G}} = \frac{1}{1+H G_c G}$$

Comment: are you sure? As you can see the answer doesn't contain a $G_C$ actually... I initially obtained the same as you did, ie with $HG_C G$ rather than only HG in the denominator

Comment: The sensitivity of the system is affected by \$H\$, \$G_c\$, and \$G\$. That's correct.  But I don't see any expression for \$G_c\$ in the question. Probably it is mentioned somewhere as being 1?

Comment: Well no, strangely enough, nothing is mentionned anywhere about G_c.

Comment: The question is incomplete if no value for \$G_c\$ is given. We need it to compute the sensitivity.

Comment: I agree with you. I'll have a short wait, see if anybody else has another suggestion. If not I'll accept your answer

Comment: I looked at the problem in 'Dorf and Bishop' and I see that the closed-loop time constant is computed as \$3/101\$. This is true only if \$G_c=1\$. So I think that's what's assumed in the problem.